# Keycloak provider setup

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I'm trying to connect via any provider, mainly facebook, using keycloak on a flutter application.
The things that I didfor now are:

- Made an app with facebook api and got a client id and secret. (I don't know if I did that correctly though)
- configured the provider and provided the necessary info in the provider's section in keycloak
- tried calling in postman the endpoint and got an error
  ```
  {
      "error": "RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header"
  }
  ```

Can someone guide me please? or at least tell me where did I go wrong.

Comment: Can you please post the request from your postman here? It is unclear which endpoint you are calling and what data you are sending.

Comment: I'm not sending any data, I don't know the format or what should I be sending in the first place. I'm calling this endpoint "/broker/facebook/endpoint"

Comment: Try to open Keycloak login page in a browser: `https://<your host>/auth/realms/<your realm>/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=<your client id>`
There you should the a Login button for Facebook.

Comment: It didn't work, it tells me bad request. But anyways, I want to use it from my app, can't seem to find out how, did anyone do it before?!